# CSS alignment problems (float vs text-align)

Tags: css-float

I'm trying to lay 3 things out on my forum: a bunch of media links top left, a menu bar top right and a logo beneath them centered.

Using this approach it appears exactly how I wanted on my localhost setup. However when I upload them to my live website, it looks different? Different in the sense that the logo seems to "see" the media box as its left margin, whereas offline is disregards it and centers on the page. Same browser, everything is the same which is why it's so baffling.

```
#logo{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }


#brdmenu {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

#media {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

I hope this isn't spammy but full CSS (and how it looks live) can be seen here: www.strengthandfitness.co.uk

Comment: Extra tip: you don't need `display:block` on the logo, a `div` is block-level by default.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be a lack of width on the #logo. Updated code, works for me in Chrome/FF:

```
#logo {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
}
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help -- just remember that when you use margin: 0 auto to center an object, it needs a width.